# What is the value of $\int_0^1\pi e^{i\pi t}dt$?

Tags: integration, contour-integration

What is the integration of the following equation?

$$\int_0^1Z(t)dt =\int_0^1\pi e^{i\pi t}dt$$

Comment: Can you show your attempt? Do you know Euler's formula $e^{i\theta}?$

Comment: The result is $2i$.

Comment: For next time, consider using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format your math properly.

Comment: @user159888 I didn't remember that formula. :(

Comment: @user thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The integral of $\int_0^1 \pi e^{i\pi t}\ dt$ Is by u substitution with $u = i\pi t$ and $du/dt= i\pi$ is equal to (also substituting the bounds) $\frac{\pi}{i\pi}\int_0^{i\pi}e^udu$. Since the antiderivative of $e^u$ is $e^u$, again substituting in  the bounds and using Euler's identity, we get $-1/i-1/i=2i$.